# Sharepoint Provider Hosted Add In using .Net Core application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-core, sharepoint-online

I am currently attempting to take an application that I have already created as a .Net CORE Application and connect it to Sharepoint Online in the form of a Provider Hosted Sharepoint Add In.

It seems that Sharepoint add ins can only recognise .Net Framework web applications which would result in having to port the .Net CORE application to a .Net Application.

I am seeking the easiest and cleanest way to proceed with this.

Is there a way that I can create a Provider Hosted app using .Net core or should I port the .NET Core application to a .Net Framework web application?

If so, how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Even we were trying to achieve the same thing. But we ended up in .net framework. To be on the safer side, you can create a provider hosted app using visual studio, which gives better connectivity to the Sharepoint App.

.Net core to .Net framework conversion would be so simple, since the framework holds most of the libraries and functionalities when compared to .Net core. You can just copy paste the code from your.net core and you can do modifications to fit in the framework.

Otherwise, you can use oauth tokens by using SharePoint Rest API's. If you have already built the provider hosted app and installed it in your site collection, you can just use the existing client id, client secret to get the access token like [this](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/access-sharepoint-rest-api-using-oauth/). So that you can perform everything using your existing .Net core app.